# Putting an existing Nifi process group into a new process group

Tags: apache-nifi, process-group

I am brand new to Nifi, and am still trying to figure out the basics. However, this is something I can't currently find with research.

I have been tasked to put a bunch of existing process groups in a flow that result in the same end process into a new process group. Dragging and dropping doesn't work, how do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: can u pls tell me the process group hierarchy u had, and also from which process group to which process group ? I could try to help u out

Comment: I can try. I have a starting process group that takes a file and parses it. That then goes to a process group where it sorts the data, and pushes it to an option of 12 process groups that then store/analyze the data. If there is an error, every process group of the 12 goes to the same error process group that sends out an email of the error. I am trying to put those 12 process groups into one big process group to make the flow more organized

Comment: Add a new Process Group. Shift + Click to select all Processors & Groups. Drag & drop ontop of the new Process Group. The new Process Group will high light in blue to show you when you are hovering in the right place.